# Count down timer where user enter timer length in one activity and he can see toast of timer status on another activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a count down timer, and it has to be like that:
The user will enter number of minutes in timerActivity and press "play"
The timerActivity will go to background and the user returned to previous activity
name commentsActivity.
every minute the user get a "Toast" saying how much time left.

I tried many possibilities including "chrono" and i will appreciate the help

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the user input activity with startWithResult and let the first activity handle the timer with the toast.

Answer (score 0):

try it to using the runnable

```
Handler  handler = new  Handler ();
int i = the minute in second
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000L);
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                i = i - 1;
                // make a Toast using i
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000L);
        }
    };
```